# User Profile Synchronization and server farm account issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have SharePoint 2013 farm with 1 Application server and 2 web server on load balance. My user profile is up and running with Server Farm Account. But it always throw below error.

[image]
So I tried to create another managed account and tried to start UPS service but it never success. I tried lot of goggling on internet but all article tells that UPS will work on only with Server Farm Account.

So now what is wrong Health Error Message or What we are doing that.

Comment: You can safely ignore this error as long as the failing service is the UPS.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with the Health Analyzer.  To function properly you must use a Farm Account for the User Profile Service Application, this causes the Health Analyzer to report the above output. The Health Analyzer Rule output is expected, but can be safely ignored for the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: Can I get any official announcement or article on it,

Answer (score 0):

From the TechNet article:

This message can be ignored. The User Profile Synchronization Service must run as the farm account.

The detailed information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750254(v=office.14).aspx#alert